What work on min max connectivity problems has there been?
For instance has min max spanning/steiner/prize-collecting tree been studied. i.e.  each edge $e$ has costs $c_{v,e}$ of each resource $i$.
And we wish to find a spanning tree minimizing the maximum amount of any resource used.
Is this NP hard for fixed number of resources and if so I'm looking for approximation algorithms.

The problem is NP-complete even for the special case of finding a spanning tree, with just two resources . See e.g. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02032304 .

@NealYoung  My previous post aimed at multiobjective single cost, now I'm inquiring what if the cost contains multiple resources.

This paper on robust s-t path is relevant and has pointers to some other problems. https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.16439
